# Как правильно построить сложные связи в CoreData?

Tags: swift, coredata

я разбираюсь с CoreData, для обучения я решил создать небольшое приложение по учету доходов и расходов пользователя. Туториалы по кор дате все как один содержат примеры Аля To-Do-List, и хороших примеров, которые помогли бы мне, я не нашел.

Когда я стал продумывать, как я буду реализовывать приложение, я предположил что самый удобный способ будет сохранять все операции пользователя, и в приложении в нужных местах производить расчеты. Пока что абстрактно, т.к. мне кажется это мало относится к вопросу, если нужно точнее, я могу предоставить полную картину.

Итак, я собираюсь сохранять модель пользователя, которая будет иметь следующие данные:

Операции пользователя (Тип Operation) - будут сохраняться все операции, каждая операция включает в себя категорию, по которой произведена операция, а так же сумма в валюте.

Категории, выбранные пользователем (Тип Category) - Категории, по которым будут идти расходы или доходы при добавлении операции.

Кошельки (Тип Wallet) - Кошельки пользователя, Тут все просто, название, и остаток средств на нем.

Бюджетные единицы (Тип BudgetUnit) - Это бюджеты пользователя, содержит категорию, и бюджет по ней. Например Продукты - 10.000 Р

[image: Категории на рисунке, для лучшего понимания]

Когда я стал выстраивать зависимости в CoreData, у меня получилась немного странная картина.

[image: Странная картина]

То есть пользователь имеет зависимость с той же моделью категорий, с которой имеет зависимость Бюджетная единица, и операция. Что то мне подсказывает что так оно работать не будет.
Я хочу чтобы категории пользователя были независимыми, он их выбрал, и я собираюсь их отображать на главном экране, а у каждой операции будет своя моделька категории, тоже самое и у бюджетной единицы.

[image: Ожидание]

На картинке выше модель категории используется 3 раза, одна и таже модель. Вот так, примерно, я представляю структуру данных, которую хотел бы видеть. У разных моделей есть своя модель категории, независимо от других.

Я думаю, это можно было бы реализовать, используя 3 разные модели с одинаковыми значениями, но, мне кажется, такой подход считается неправильным.

Так как же правильно реализовать модель данных, чтобы все работало как положено? Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: категории связал бы только с операциями, а операции с пользователями. И, соответственно, делал вычисления для кошельков и бюджетов, по каким операциям (категориям) делал расходы пользователь.

[image: Модель CoreData]